# Powershell - Compare Folder Contents

Tags: powershell, comparison

I have the below code which compares the two folders and outputs the files different with respect to each folder, is there a way to get this to output the full file/folder path for files in subfolders?

Cheers

```
 # Create varaibles to store folder paths - pass to Strings... 
 param([string]$argFolderA,[string]$argFolderB)

 # Set variables for folder
 $FolderA = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $argFolderA
 $FolderB = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $argFolderB

 # Compare the contents and output the files different within each folder. 
 Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FolderA -DifferenceObject $FolderB >> C:\CmpOut.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the Passthru flag of the Comapre-Object like so:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FolderA -DifferenceObject $FolderB -Passthru | % {$_.FullName}  >> C:\CmpOut.txt
```

Comment: In this way SideIndicator is lost.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FolderA -DifferenceObject $FolderB  | 
select @{n="InputObject";e={ 
     if ($_.inputobject -is [system.io.directoryinfo]) 
     {([system.io.DirectoryInfo]$_.InputObject).fullname}
      else 
      { ([system.io.FileInfo]$_.InputObject).fullname}}},SideIndicator
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it through `ForEach {$_.InputObject.FullName}`.

Like this:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FolderA -DifferenceObject $FolderB | ForEach {$_.InputObject.FullName}
```

Comment: In this way SideIndicator is lost.

Comment: It's not lost...it's available via `$_.SideIndicator`.